# Respond yes and y for multiple prompts Linux commandline

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I have a program I'm trying to automatically install in a DockerFile, that has 3 prompts requiring yes/y responses.

1 - y
2 - explicit "yes"
3 - y

is there a command like yes that I can chain together responses?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just use `yes yes | ./executable` and that will cover both `y` and `yes` responses